# toString in subClasses Cannot Override abstract toString , Java

Tags: java, tostring

I have this very long exercise and I came a cross a problem in each sub class.
The problem says  and I have no idea what mistake I've made while writing.
If you could check the 4 toString methods I would be much apprecaited .

The code is here: http://paste.org/pastebin/view/39488 
I know I should past the code here but it is very long and I'm not able to organize it well.

`toString() in Shape cannot override toString() in java.lang.Object; attempting to use incompatible return type`

`toString() in Square cannot override toString() in java.lang.Object; attempting to use incompatible return type`
`

`toString() in Sphere cannot override toString() in java.lang.Object; attempting to use incompatible return type`

`toString() in Cube cannot override toString() in java.lang.Object; attempting to use incompatible return type`

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the return type of the function to `String` and return the text instead of writing it to `System.out`.

```
public String toString() {
    return  "(" + super.getX() + ", " +
    super.getY() +") " + "side: " + super.getDimension1();
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to have a method that outputs the object directly to `System.out` in textual form, you'll need to call it something else than `toString()`. This is because `toString()` is a method belonging to `java.lang.Object` which all Java classes automatically extend.

Comment: I just did that, but the output is totally different when I used a random method I called print before I realized the question wants it as toString

Comment: There should be no output from calling `toString()`. Try updating your `displayShapeInfo()` so that instead of `shapeArray[ i ].toString();` you call `System.out.println(shapeArray[ i ].toString());`

Answer (score 5):

toString() has to return `String` not `void`.

```
// false
public abstract void toString();

// right
public abstract String toString();
```

Note: You should not print (System.out) in the toString() method. You should rather return a String represenation of the object.

Comment: is there a way I could return System.out ? because I think I made a mistake from the beginning and this will cost me rewriting the whole program again :S

Comment: Return System.out makes no sense. toString() has to return a String.

Answer (score 1):

because you try to override it with a void return type.  toString should return a String.

Answer (score 1):

It should return a string and not void.

```
public abstract String toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` is implemented in `Object` class and every class extends it. This method is in every class and we can't have two method with same signature but different return type.
As `toString()` is already there with return type `String`, we can't have one more `toString()` with any other return type.